# Проблема прогресс-бара

Tags: python, progress-bar

Напсал прогресс-бар (с помощю другого человека) и уткнулся в проблему: когда 100 не делится на n прогресс-бар оканчивается 100-(n-1). Прошу помочь в решении.
Вот код:

```
z=int(input()) #Задаём сколько раз повторять
for j in range(z):
    v=int(input()) #Задаём сколько ждать между каждым шагом
    if __name__ == "__main__":
     x='#'
    n=int(input()) #Задаём шаг: сколько процентов будет обозначать каждая решоточка:'#'
    ProgressMax = 100 
    for i in range(1, ProgressMax+1):
        if i*n <=  ProgressMax:
            print(x*i , str(i*n)+'%', '\r', end=' ')
        else:
           break
        time.sleep(v/10)
```

Comment: А вы какие значения вводили?

Comment: 3,7,11,13,17...

Comment: это куда вводили а сколько шаг каждой #

Comment: да да да да да да

Comment: проблема в том что он не доходит до 100?

Comment: да.......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
import time
z = int(input()) #Задаём сколько раз повторять
for j in range(z):
    v = int(input()) #Задаём сколько ждать между каждым шагом
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        x='#'
    n = float(input()) #Задаём шаг: сколько процентов будет обозначать каждая решеточка:'#'
    progressMax = 100 
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i*n <=  progressMax:
            print(x*i , str(i*n)+'%', '\r', end=' ')
        else:
            print(x*i , str(100.0)+'%', '\r', end=' ')
            break
        time.sleep(v/10)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Зачем в конце i+=1?

Comment: что бы процент увеличивался. Работает?

Comment: Работает.......

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде норм работает

```
import time

set_repeat = int(input('Количество повторов: '))  # Задаём сколько раз повторять
set_interval = int(input('Время задержки: '))  # Задаём сколько ждать между каждым шагом
set_step = int(input('Шаг: '))  # Задаём шаг: сколько процентов будет обозначать каждая решоточка:'#'
ProgressMax = 100


def main(repeat, interval, step, symb):
    for j in range(repeat):
        for i in range(1, ProgressMax + 1):
            if i * step <= ProgressMax:
                print(str(symb * i) + ' ' + str(i * step)+' %', '\r', end=' ')
            else:
                break
            time.sleep(interval / 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(set_repeat, set_interval, set_step, '#')
```

Comment: def-это цикл???

Comment: `def` Это описание функции, а внутри функции у нас происходит цикл. А из конструкции `__name__=='__main__'` мы эту функцию вызываем. Кстати инпуты тоже в функцию бросить можно

Comment: Выдаёт ошбку в 10-ой строке

Comment: А вы точно правильно параметры передаёте? И какие параметры? И что за ошибка ?

Comment: Я даже параметры не успел ввести. Пишет SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: А питон какой версии у вас?

Comment: 3-ей............

Comment: Вы точно код не меняли? Он работает идеально, если что

Comment: ДА.............

Comment: Я проверял на онлайн компиляторе:  OnlineGDB beta

Comment: Он не доходит до с 100

Comment: Я же спросил про версию питона, исправил код под вашу версию

Comment: Вижу. В Вашем коде нет "функции" ...  Что-бы вывод имел вид:##...#100%    а не: #10%                                                                                                                                           ##20%                                                                                                                                     #...##100%

Comment: Работает как надо, чуток вывод поправил